# Outlook 2011 Meetings - how to add as an attachment?

Tags: email, ms-office

I'm trying to get Outlook for Mac to do what Outlook for Windows has done for a long time.

I want to create an email, attach a meeting to the email and send it - I don't want just the meeting details summarized as text (what seems to happen), I want the whole meeting to be added to my email as an attachment.

I loved this feature in Windows as I could send the meeting to a non-participant to keep them in the loop and not have to redact any details, but at the same time, it didn't pop up on the recipient's calendar the way a forwarded meeting does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Outlook:Mac calendar, drag the meeting tile from your calendar to your desktop or a Finder window.  It will create a new file named MyMeetingTitle.ics.  You can then create your new email and attach this .ics file to it.  Your recipient will then be able to add this .ics file to their calendar.